# Change height on div with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, height

I want to set the height on a div when the div is more than 100px in height.

For example, when the content of the div makes the div's height fill more than 100px, I want it automatically fit to 200 px.

Comment: you can get/set css with getElementById('id').style in pure javascript or with $('#id').css (...) in jQuery? what problem you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is to make sure there is no "height" attribute in the elements CSS (inline styling is fine). Then, when the content is changed call this function:

```
if ($('#myDiv').height() > 100) {
    // Div is larger than 100px so increase it to 200px
    $('#myDiv').css('height', '200px');
}
```

Comment: The issue is that you'll have to call this function whenever the content of that div changes. Not sure if that's what they are looking for but that'll work, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `min-height` CSS property is what you are looking for:

```
div#myDiv {
    min-height: 100px;
    height: auto; 
    display: block; /* float won't work */
}
```

This *should* automatically resize your div to wrap its whole content dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

***You can try***

```
if($("divID").height() > 100){
    $("divID").css("height","200px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just work with min-height and max-height with CSS.

```
div#myDiv {
min-height: 100px;
height: auto;
max-height: 200px;
}
```

you could also do something with javascript as said, but with this you can also have the possibility that the height is 150px, or 120px. if you don't want that, You should do it the javascript-way.